# Get maximum element of list of list if condition is met

Tags: python, list, loops, nested, list-comprehension

I have list of lists:

```
 [[[10, 15, 200, 220], [10, 15, 200, 220], 0.0],
 [[10, 15, 200, 220], [20, 25, 200, 230], 17.320508075688775],
 [[110, 150, 240, 300], [10, 15, 200, 220], 190.3286631067428],
 [[110, 150, 240, 300], [100, 150, 230, 300], 14.142135623730951],
 [[110, 150, 240, 300], [110, 150, 240, 300], 0.0]]
```

I want to get maximum value of each element in a list, if the third real number is less than a threshold (let's say 50). In other words in the above case, the desired resulst would be:

1) filter results based on the threshold, e.g.

```
 [[[10, 15, 200, 220], [10, 15, 200, 220], 0.0],
 [[10, 15, 200, 220], [20, 25, 200, 230], 17.320508075688775],
 [[110, 150, 240, 300], [100, 150, 230, 300], 14.142135623730951],
 [[110, 150, 240, 300], [110, 150, 240, 300], 0.0]]
```

2) get maximum of each element in list:

```
[20, 25, 200, 230]
[110, 150, 240, 300]
```

Comment: You mean to say 0.0, 17.320508075688775,... is less than 50?

Comment: @ThatBird yes,calculate results for cases where that real value (0.0, 17.320508075688775...) is less than 50.

Comment: what's the meaning of `2) get maximum of each element in list` ? how did you get only 2 results from 4 lists??

Comment: @lenik yes, you are right. i don't know how to expain it well. Can I filter the list by mean value of its elements and sort of get 2 results at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> L = [[[10, 15, 200, 220], [10, 15, 200, 220], 0.0],
...  [[10, 15, 200, 220], [20, 25, 200, 230], 17.320508075688775],
...  [[110, 150, 240, 300], [10, 15, 200, 220], 190.3286631067428],
...  [[110, 150, 240, 300], [100, 150, 230, 300], 14.142135623730951],
...  [[110, 150, 240, 300], [110, 150, 240, 300], 0.0]]
```

You can filter the lists of lists on the last element with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [M for M in L if M[-1]<50]  
[[[10, 15, 200, 220], [10, 15, 200, 220], 0.0], [[10, 15, 200, 220], [20, 25, 200, 230], 17.320508075688775], [[110, 150, 240, 300], [100, 150, 230, 300], 14.142135623730951], [[110, 150, 240, 300], [110, 150, 240, 300], 0.0]]
```

Now, to merge the previous lists, you can use a zip (I added a filter on `0` that is implied by the desired output):

```
>>> [[max(*xs) for xs in zip(*M[:-1])] for M in L if 0<M[-1]<50]  
[[20, 25, 200, 230], [110, 150, 240, 300]]
```

Explanation: the idea is to zip the lists, e.g.:

```
>>> list(zip([10, 15, 210, 220], [10, 25, 200, 250]))
[(10, 10), (15, 25), (210, 200), (220, 250)]
```

And to take the greatest element of tuples:

```
>>> [max(x,y) for x,y in zip([10, 15, 210, 220], [10, 25, 200, 250])]
[10, 25, 210, 250]
```

I used the star operator to make the code more flexible: it doesn't rely on the number of lists:

```
>>> list(zip([10, 15, 210, 220], [10, 25, 200, 250], [15, 20, 210, 260]))
[(10, 10, 15), (15, 25, 20), (210, 200, 210), (220, 250, 260)]
>>> [max(*xs) for xs in zip([10, 15, 210, 220], [10, 25, 200, 250], [15, 20, 210, 260])]
[15, 25, 210, 260]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [[[10, 15, 200, 220], [10, 15, 200, 220], 0.0],
 [[10, 15, 200, 220], [20, 25, 200, 230], 17.320508075688775],
 [[110, 150, 240, 300], [10, 15, 200, 220], 190.3286631067428],
 [[110, 150, 240, 300], [100, 150, 230, 300], 14.142135623730951],
 [[110, 150, 240, 300], [110, 150, 240, 300], 0.0]]
filtered = [i for i in a if i[2] < 50.0]
[get_maximum( i ) for i in filtered]
```

Which will work once you explain what does "2) get maximum of each element in list:" means or implement it yourself.